# StringBuilder ToString injects \n\r

Tags: .net, newline, stringbuilder

When I execute this .Net code:

```
   var builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.AppendLine("Line One");
   builder.AppendLine("Line Two");
   var result = builder.ToString();
```

The value of result is literally:

```
"Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n"
```

Why is the .ToString() converting the newlines to "\r\n" text and is there a way to prevent this and have the string actually have real (hidden) newline characters?

Comment: Where are you seeing the "result" value?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `"Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n"`. Have you tried to put `result` to a multiline textbox?.

Comment: In the visual studio debugger I "copy" the value of "result" and paste it into Notepad, and instead of actual line breaks I see all the \r\n characters. Curiously, if I instead "copy" the value of "builder" it pastes into Notepad correctly.

Comment: What happened is you copied the string literal result. Like @I4V said, try just going Console.WriteLine(result); If you were to create a string literal that has newlines in it you would type just that "Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n".

Answer (score 2):

In the debugger it displays the 'escape characters' that is the carriage return new line standard windows eol string. If you were to print that out to say the command line or file. You will get an actual new line. All escape characters begin with '\' in c#. So \r\n, the \r is carriage return, the \n is line feed or new line.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Also to properly code this in c#

```
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.AppendLine("Line One");
   builder.AppendLine("Line Two");
   String result = builder.ToString();
```

This is also another way of writing the same thing

```
String result = "Line One\r\nLine Two\r\n";
```